# Passenger with apache fails with "End time can not be before or equal to begin time"

Tags: apache, ubuntu-16.04, passenger

Running Passenger 6.0.4 with Apache 2.4.18 on Ubuntu 64 bit server 16.04.

I have a virtual system set up and whenever I try to access it Passenger quits with the subject message.  I have not been able to find any suggestion about what might be wrong.

I have a couple of cloud servers set up with over 100 virtual hosts using ubuntu 14.04 but I want to move up to a supported version.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error when attempting to setup an instance of Canvas LMS.  I resolved this by simply adding a folder called "passenger" in the /tmp folder.

That's needed for Passenger to run properly and for some reason wasn't created on it's own.